# How can I draw lines on the edges of objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, post-processing, image-effects

I'm making a unity SteamVR game.

I want to achieve an unlit art style reminiscent of Antichamber.

I want to draw lines on the edges of objects, but I couldn't find an online solution that was not outdated and that worked.

Here is a picture from antichamber.
[image: Here is a picture from antichamber.]

You can see that every object has a line across all of it's edges.

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do this with Unity's "*Edge Detect Effect Normals*" which is part of Unity's image effects and is included in their Standard Assets. You can get it [here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/legacy-image-effects-83913).

---

There is also a new image effect for Unity called ["Post Processing Stack"](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912) which is really faster than the one I linked above and you can get that here. Edge Detect is not included in the new "Post Processing Stack" image effects but if you decide to use the new Post Processing Stack, you can get the ported version of "*Edge Detect Effect Normals*" [here](https://github.com/jean-moreno/EdgeDetect-PostProcessingUnity).

Any one of these effects can draw lines on edges of objects.

Comment: is there a shader version of this instead of post processing?

Comment: do you have an updated version - links no longer work

Answer (score -1):

> I want to draw lines on the edges of objects

This free asset promises to do just that.

"**Supports outlines with variable thickness, color, that work in Editor, Ortho and Perspective cameras.**"

Source: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/toon-shader-free-21288

Comment: That's not what I am looking for.
The shader only outlines the object, and doesn't draw a line on every edge.

Comment: I believe that a shader should still be able to solve that somehow. Albeit not the shader shown in the asset then.

Comment: probably, an image effect would probably work even better because it won't  matter what object you're looking at.

Comment: What do you mean by "image effect"?

Comment: A shader the affects the camera's view using a c# script.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.RenderWithShader.html that is possible yes.